# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13) but 'localhost' works

Tags: centos, mysql, php

Cent os Apache + php + MySQL from php when you try to connect to the MySQL at the address 127.0.0.1, an error occurs. If you replace a line `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` everything works without problems. The only problem with php in browser. If the console execute

```
php -r "var_dump (mysqli_connect ( '127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name'))"
```

is no error. Also, if the console to enter the

```
mysql -u user -h 127.0.0.1 -p db_name
```

or

```
mysql -u user -h localhost -p db_name
```

too, everything works. What could be the Problem?

Software versions

- PHP-5.6.26
- MySQL-5.5.53
- Apache 2.2.15

Finally,

```
$ host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
```

php code working:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

php code not working:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'dbuser';
    $password = 'dbpass';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)

php code working:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

php code not working:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

**solution:**

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

Comment: host localhost - localhost has address 127.0.0.1

Comment: did you check here ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413728/connect-mysql-through-localhost-not-working-but-127-0-0-1-is-working

Comment: Tried not work, it seems the problem is not in Mysql

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 3):

According to [this (unaccepted) answer over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31414252/2344631), the reason is that MySQL interprets `localhost` differently to `127.0.0.1`. This is [confirmed in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html), see the paragraph starting, "*On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name `localhost` specially*".

- The `127.0.0.1` is an explicit IPv4 address, so the client attempts to connect over TCP/IP
- The `localhost` is an implicit hint to use the local host, which MySQL implements, where possible, via a local socket rather than over TCP/IP

Since your `localhost` connection works but the `127.0.0.1` one doesn't, it seems possible that one of these issues is the culprit:

- your database permissions deny a connection from `127.0.0.1`
- you have a firewall rule blocking all inbound database connection attempts over TCP/IP
- you have changed the `bind` configuration entry for MySQL so that it doesn't bind on the loopback address

Given the error code 13 (*permission denied*), I would investigate the first of these before the other two.

Comment: I think this answer is on track, though there's something a little weird going on, here.  The number at the end `(13)` is unusual.  That's the system error code, and error 13 is `Permission denied`.  The expected values would be 111 `Connection refused` or (for an iptables-type issue) 110 `Connection timed out`.  This error is client-side, so it's odd the client would lack "permission" to *attempt* a TCP connection.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good catch. See what you think to the amended answer

Comment: For Root Users have all the 3 ways to access %, lokalhost, 127.0.0.1.
Firewall disabled. In my.cnf no parameters bind-address and the skip-networking.

Comment: @CarlW. if this answers helps you please remember to mark it as the accepted answer. If it doesn't, please explain what is still missing.